# Changing tasks.json's output destination

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, gcc, vscode-tasks

So, I want to get into assembly programming, and for that, I tried configuring a tasks.json, so that I don't have to type out the commands every time I compile. So far it works great, I added an assembling task, another tasks, that assembles and links, and another one that does both and then also runs the .exe in the terminal. This is where my problem arises: There is a tasks terminal, with all of the logs, of the tasks that are being executed. With my current configuration, the .exe's output also gets printed inside of the tasks terminal, making the actual output harder to find amongst all of the logs. So, my question is: Is it possible to configure the tasks.json in such a way, that it always outputs to, let's say, a new integrated powershell?

Here is the tasks.json so far:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "assemble-asm",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "nasm",
        "args": ["-f", "win32", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj", "${file}"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "panel": "shared"
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
      },
      {
        "label": "Assemble and Link",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc",
        "args": ["${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "panel": "shared"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "dependsOn": "assemble-asm"
      },
      {
        "label": "Run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "panel": "shared",
          "echo": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "dependsOn": "Assemble and Link"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered using a launch config instead for your "Run" task and the `preLaunchTask` launch config property?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I don't think you can add a debugger for assembly, right?

Comment: excuse me. I think I was working of some poor intuition.